# Is it OK to have callback to view inside a WPF command when we are using MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, callback, command

I want to know If I am violating MVVM pattern if I put a logic in command execute method that invokes a callback method passed to it through the parameter?

for example:

```
public void MyCommandExecute(object arg)
{
if(arg is System.Action)
   {
        (arg as System.Action)(); //this action will do any logic about the view
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some code for your question. But it does not sound like it if your call back can implements inotifypropertychanged, and updates the view.

Comment: @StuartSmith code added.

Comment: Instead of passing a callback as a command parameter, you should have a property (with change notification) that the view can bind to. The command execution method would just set that property.

Comment: I want to know what's the problem with this type of callback. Implementation would be very straight forward. 
I know I can change a property and in the view handle the propertychanged event. @Clemens

Comment: @Mohammadamin Khayat 

As per MVVM, you need to notify the view by raising the PropertyChanged event. You can implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface for your view model class.
I think you're not aware of the MVVM pattern completely. This type of callback is also possible. But it's upto you to have a better design that separates the view and data.

Comment: @vishakh369 - I don't think that with this practice I am making a dependency from ViewModel to View. because the ViewModel still does not know anything about the View. The passed argument that realizes the callback is something completely loose coupled.

Comment: Actually MVVM is separating the business logic and design logic. We use view model mainly for binding data defining properties and all. Direct view related code can be defined in the  view itself. Say for eg: you have defined a button in your view with close and you want your window to close when user clicks on it. This can be defined in the view itself, rather than using the viewmodel for that. so both ways are correct. The callback is possible. You could directly do that in your view. That's what I am trying to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually MVVM is separating the business logic and design logic. We use view model mainly for binding data defining properties and all. Direct view related code can be defined in the  view itself. Say for eg: you have defined a button in your view with close and you want your window to close when user clicks on it. This can be defined in the view itself, rather than using the viewmodel for that. so both ways are correct. The callback is possible. You could directly do that in your view. That's what I am trying to say.